# Convergence Of The Following Alternating series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can I show that this series:
 $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{\sin n\theta}{n} $$

converges for every $\theta$?

Could anyone give me an advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The series in fact converges absolutely and thus it converges (alternatingly), since:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sin k\theta=\frac{\cos\frac\theta2-\cos\left(n+\frac12\right)\theta}{2\sin\frac\theta2}\implies\left|\sum_{k=1}^n\sin k\theta\right|\le\frac1{\left|\sin\frac\theta2\right|}$$

and $\;\cfrac1n\rightarrow0\;$ monotonically , so we can use [Dirichlet's Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test) to deduce the result.